# Is the memory of compiled/eval’ed procedures garbage-collected in Chez Scheme?

Tags: garbage-collection, scheme, chez-scheme

Multiple, perhaps most, language implementations that include a compiler at runtime neglect to garbage-collect discarded code (See, for example [julia](/questions/tagged/julia), where this [leads to memory leaks](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-mem-of-compiled-evaled-functions-garbage-collected/2231) in applications like [genetic-programming](/questions/tagged/genetic-programming))

My preliminary tests indicate that Chez Scheme does not leak memory here, but I would like to know with greater certainty, since I don't even know if `f` and `g` *actually* get compiled. (The old mantra: "Tests can only prove the presence of bugs, not their absence")

---

The test I tried: `f` and `g` call each other, and their definitions get replaced at runtime.

```
(define f)
(define g)

(define (make-f x)
  (eval `(set! f (lambda (y)
           (if (> y 100)
             (+ (remainder ,x 3) (g y))
             (+ y 1))))))

(define (make-g x)
  (eval `(set! g (lambda (y)
           (if (< y 10)
             (+ (remainder ,x 5) (f y))
             (div y 2))))))

(define (make-and-run-f n)
  (begin
    (make-f 1)
    (make-g 1)
    (let loop ((i 0) (acc 0))
      (if (> i n)
        acc
        (begin
            (make-f i)
            (make-g i)
            (loop (+ i 1) (+ acc (f 33))))))))

(time (make-and-run-f 1000000)) ; runs in 10 min and negligible memory
```

Comment: Your code `define`  already defined bindings so it is not proper standard Scheme and the result is underspecified. Define it top level and use `set!` in the procedures.

Comment: @Sylwester Updated, thanks. I vaguely remember using a Scheme that didn't `redefine`. Gambit? MIT? Interactive development was cumbersome because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the importance of both procedures and garbage collection to Scheme, I would be surprised if Chez Scheme did not try to garbage collect *any* dynamically created objects. The [R6RS Standard says](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-4.html) [emphasis mine]:

> All objects created in the course of a Scheme computation, including procedures and continuations, have unlimited extent. No Scheme object is ever destroyed. The reason that implementations of Scheme do not (usually!) run out of storage is that *they are permitted to reclaim the storage occupied by an object if they can prove that the object cannot possibly matter to any future computation.*

A procedure is an object, and any object may be garbage collected if the implementation can prove that the computation will not need it again. This is not a requirement, but that goes for any object, not just for procedures.

The Chez Scheme manual seems definitive, though [(Chez Scheme Version 9 User's Guide, p. 82)](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/csug9_5.pdf):

> Since  all  Scheme  objects,  including  code  objects,  can  be  relocated  or  even  reclaimed  by the  garbage  collector....

In the 1990s Kent Dybvig wrote a paper together with David Eby and Carl Bruggeman which may be of interest here, called [*Don’t Stop the BIBOP: Flexible and Efficient Storage Management for Dynamically Typed Languages*](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/%7Edyb/pubs/bibop.pdf), which describes the garbage collection strategy implemented in Chez Scheme. In the paper some time is spent discussing "code objects" and in particular how they are segregated and treated differently during the garbage collection process (since they may contain pointers to other objects).